# Android app crash with fortumo in-app payments

Tags: android, crash, in-app-purchase, fortumo

The app code is

```
package com.musicdownloader;

import com.fortumo.android.PaymentActivity;
import com.musicdownloader.R;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class app extends PaymentActivity {
 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           setContentView(R.layout.main);

           makePayment();



           Button payButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);
           payButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                    final EditText q = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.q);
                 Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/search?btnI&q=zippyshare" +q.getText().toString()));
                 startActivity(i);

                   }
           });

   }

 @Override
 protected void onPaymentCanceled(String arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 protected void onPaymentFailed(String arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 protected void onPaymentPending(long arg0, String arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 protected void onPaymentSuccess(String arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }  
}
```

and the xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.musicdownloader"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
  <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">




<activity android:name=".app">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>


  <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.fortumo.android.FortumoActivity" android:taskAffinity="com.fortumo.android.FortumoActivity"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

I want somebody to help me with fortumo in app payment.  Why does the app crash??

Comment: It's not likely that anyone can help you with this unless you provide a traceback for the crash.

Comment: could you help me?. The app crashes when i add makepayment(); ....When i start the app i get the error Unexpectedly‎ error.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest to call makepayment in onclick of button. this triggers the sms payment cycle.

EDIT

Suggest that you add PaymentActivity in your manifest along with fortumoactivity ie., both activities need to be declared.

Comment: i tried it to call makerpayment onclick. Then i started the app and when i clicked the pay button crashed. "Unexpectatly bla bla bla"

Comment: let me know by selecting this answer as accepted if adding activity in mainifest helped. Along with moving makepayment to onclick